# How do I match a full link in capybara?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

In Capybara+Rspec, I can check that a link is missing:

```
response.body.should_not have_link("link_content")
```

This is fine, but unfortunately the test fails for when "link_content" partially matches a link, such as "this_is_a_long_link_content". How can I change the test to make it pass in this case?

(That is, the matcher should not partially match, it should only fully match).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the following workaround:

```
response.body.should_not have_xpath("//a[normalize-space(text())='link_content']")
```

This is whitespace-agnostic and therefore a little more flexible than the raw HTML approach.

Comment: Did not know xpath can so powerfull, it's good to know that (and it means that your answer deserves to be upvoted ;)). However, the raw HTML approach can be easily made whitespace-agnostic too - pls see my edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:

> If all else fails, you can also use the page.html method to test against the raw HTML:

This works for me:

```
page.html.should match('>\s*Log in\s*</a>')
page.html.should_not match('>\s*link_content\s*</a>')
```

Note that the argument to match can a regular expression. That means that you can make the solution whitespace-agnostic by simply adding `\s*`.

Comment: I didnt get round to trying it because Niklas' answer worked well, but this is a good fallback in the future, thanks.